# Как правильно пишется слово «паралелипипед»?

Tags: орфография, этимология, заимствования

Как пишется слово? Откуда оно пришло в русский язык?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **«параллелепипед»** пришло в наш язык, когда русская наука стала развиваться особенно интенсивно, в XVIII веке.

Уточнить правописание можно в орфографическом словаре. Как пишется **«параллелепипед»**, придётся запомнить, потому что ни одну букву в нём проверить нельзя, как нельзя подобрать правило, которое бы объяснило именно такое написание.

Лексема образована от двух греческих: *parallelos* (параллельный) и *epipedon* (плоскость). Как видим, первая часть полностью совпадает с написанием греческого *parallelos*. Осталось только запомнить, как пишется слово **«параллельный»**.

Источник: [Как правильно пишется слово «параллелепипед»?](https://uchipravila.ru/orfografiya/parallelepiped)